# How do I use basename in a avconv script

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to encode some flac files to mp3 for my mp3 player.

The album is titled correctly and I want to just maintain the file's basename without the suffix.

I got this:

```
for file in *.flac; do
    n='basename "$file" .flac';
    avconv -i "$file" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "$n".mp3; 
done
```

However, much to my dismay, the files are now all going to be named

```
 "'basename "$file" .flac'.mp3.
```

Any help?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: please edit question to include a sample case that illustrates your problem., ie original filename, desired filename, and current problem filename. Good luck. (use 4 spaces at the front of a line, with blank lines above and below to have an easier to read format)

Comment: This is completely unrelated to avconv - `echo "$n".mp3` would also have shown that the value of n is wrong. Please cut down the problem as much as possible before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution instead of single quotes:

```
n=$(basename "$file" .flac)
```